# net group /add /domain alternative batch file windows xp

Tags: batch-file

First post here, I'm trying to create a batch file that allows a technician to supply a text file with computer names and add them to a security group. I've written the following script that uses NET GROUP, net group /domain works, but I can't use net group %filepath% /add /domain. The environment I'm under is Windows XP. Please help! Cheers.

```
@echo off
title ModGroup
echo Discovering available groups on %USERDOMAIN%, please wait...
echo.
net group /domain > grouplist_.txt
set /p entgrpname=Type whole group name: 
findstr /i "%entgrpname%" grouplist_.txt > tmp2_.txt
(
set /p var=
)<tmp2_.txt
del tmp2_.txt
del grouplist_.txt
set var="%var:~1%"
echo.
rem ****%var% is the group name the user specified and its been verified to exist****
msg "%username%" WARNING! - You are about to edit the %var% group! - Please take extra caution whilst using this script!
echo.
echo Please enter the full filepath of the *.txt file that contains objects that you
echo want to add/remove.
echo.
set /p filepath=Filepath: 
echo.
(
set /p filepath2=
)<%filepath%
echo.
set /p addrem=Please specify if you would like to add or delete: 
cls
echo You're about to %addrem% the following objects to/from %var%:
echo.
echo %filepath2%
echo.
pause
echo.
echo Processing, please wait...
echo.

for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%i in (%filepath%) do net group %var%
%%i /%addrem% /domain

echo. 
pause
exit
```

Comment: And what/where is the problem? What does this code that it should not? What is it not doing that it should?

Comment: Echo out `%filepath%`. Does it have any spaces?

Comment: The only thing I can tell that's probably wrong is that it's not dumping all the hosts in the specified hosts file to the screen. It's correctly iterating over them all and issuing the `net group` command for each one.